# How to save ASP checkbox state in Checkstate and retrieve value after postba

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, gridview, viewstate

Am developing an ASP Webform App and having some challenges with checkbox Viewstate and Postback.
My App has 2 Gridviews. Gridview has about 8 columns and 3 of those columns has 3 TemplateFields with each TemplateField having its own ASP checkbox with a different IDs. Gridview displays data from an Active Directory which has already been assigned to a user will be updated, deleted, or unchanged. i want to use the checkboxes checked states or values for the updates.

Please see Markup for Gridview A

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv_ZugeteilteEmailverteiler" runat="server" AllowPaging ="true" PageSize="15" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BackColor="Silver" HeaderStyle-Height="40px" OnPreRender="gv_ZugeteilteEmailverteiler_PreRender"     
    HorizontalAlign="Center" CellPadding="0">
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reihe" ItemStyle-Width="200px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>   
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="gruppenname" HeaderText="Gruppenname" NullDisplayText="n/a" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="250px"/>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="standort" HeaderText="Standort" NullDisplayText="n/a" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="250px"/>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="beschreibung" HeaderText="Beschreibung" NullDisplayText="n/a" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="250px"/>             
    <asp:BoundField DataField="genehmigt" HeaderText="Genehmigt" NullDisplayText="n/a" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="400px"/>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="zielobjekt" HeaderText="ZielObjekt" NullDisplayText="n/a" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="250px"/>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ACTION_CHECKED" HeaderText="Action_Checked" NullDisplayText="n/a" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="250px" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Neu-Hinzufügen" ItemStyle-Width="200px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">                                                          
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="cb_EmailverteilerHinzufuegen" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Checked="false" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="checkboxClass" onclick="CheckBoxCheck(this);" onchange="return javascript:CheckBoxCheck(this);" OnCheckedChanged="cb_EmailverteilerHinzufuegen_CheckedChanged"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Entfernen" ItemStyle-Width="200px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="cb_EmailverteilerEntfernen" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="checkboxClass" onclick="CheckBoxCheck(this);" onchange="return javascript:CheckBoxCheck(this);" OnCheckedChanged="cb_EmailverteilerEntfernen_CheckedChanged"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Bestätigen" ItemStyle-Width="200px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="cb_EmailverteilerBestaetigen" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" class="checkboxClass" onclick="CheckBoxCheck(this);" onchange="return javascript:CheckBoxCheck(this);" OnCheckedChanged="cb_EmailverteilerBestaetigen_CheckedChanged"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>                                       
    </Columns>
    <HeaderStyle ForeColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" BackColor="#CCCC00"></HeaderStyle>
    </asp:GridView>
```

The Gridview B also has about 6 columns and one checkbox in a Template field. The Data in Gridview B are Directories from the AD that can be added to the user's list of already given directories shown in Gridview A. Hence when the checkbox in Gridview B is clicked, the entire row selected or checked will be added to Gridview A.

Please see the Markup for Gridview B

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv_MoeglicheEmailverteiler" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"  
AutoGenerateColumns="false" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BackColor="Silver" HeaderStyle-Height="40px" OnPreRender="gv_MoeglicheEmailverteiler_PreRender"   
HorizontalAlign="Center" CellPadding="3" CssClass="tablesorter">
<Columns>                
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reihe" ItemStyle-Width="200px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">   
<ItemTemplate>
<%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>   
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="gruppenname" HeaderText="Gruppenname" NullDisplayText="n/a" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="250px"/>                           
<asp:BoundField DataField="standort" HeaderText="Standort" NullDisplayText="n/a" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="250px"/>
<asp:BoundField DataField="beschreibung" HeaderText="Beschreibung" NullDisplayText="n/a" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="250px"/>             
<asp:BoundField DataField="genehmigt" HeaderText="Genehmigt" NullDisplayText="n/a" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="250px"/>
<asp:BoundField DataField="zielobjekt" HeaderText="ZielObjekt" NullDisplayText="n/a" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="250px"/>
<asp:BoundField DataField="ACTION_CHECKED" HeaderText="Action_Checked" NullDisplayText="n/a" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="250px" />
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="300px"  HeaderText="Action" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox ID="cb_CheckOneMoglicheverteilerRow" runat="server" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" class="checkboxClass" AutoPostBack="true" onclick = "Check_Click(this);" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox_CheckChanged"/>
</ItemTemplate>        
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
<HeaderStyle ForeColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" BackColor="#CCCC00"></HeaderStyle>                       
</asp:GridView>
```

PROBLEM: Each of the checkboxes in both Gridviews fires events. Example the Checkbox in Gridview B's Event is to add the checked Row to Gridview A. I managed to save the Gridviews ViewState and retrieve them after every Postback or event and Bind them succesfully.

My problem is, the checkboxes in Gridview A, i cannot or dont know how i could save their checkedstates in a ViewState and restore them after Postback or after an Event or after page refreshes. They all go unchecked after page refreshes or after a Postback.

Here are the methods to add a row from Gridview B to Gridview A and Remove Row from Gridview A

// Create Datatable and save in Viewstate, I was thinking i could add the checkboxes columns to the datatable here as well, but i dont know how to get their values, because the Gridview columns values i get from a database boundfield.

```
    private DataTable CreateDataTable()
    {
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      if (ViewState["SelectedRecords"] != null)
      {
         dt = (DataTable)ViewState["SelectedRecords"];
      }
      else
      {
       dt.Columns.Add("gruppenname");
       dt.Columns.Add("standort");
       dt.Columns.Add("beschreibung");
       dt.Columns.Add("genehmigt");
       dt.Columns.Add("zielobjekt");
       dt.Columns.Add("Action_Checked");
       dt.AcceptChanges();
      }
        return dt;
   }
```

// Method to add Row to from Gridview A to Gridview B

```
private DataTable AddRow(GridViewRow gvRow, DataTable dt)
  {
            DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("gruppenname = '" + gvRow.Cells[1].Text + "'");

            if (dr.Length <= 0)
            {

                dt.Rows.Add();
                dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["gruppenname"] = gvRow.Cells[1].Text;
                dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["standort"] = gvRow.Cells[2].Text;
                dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["beschreibung"] = gvRow.Cells[3].Text;
                dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["genehmigt"] = gvRow.Cells[4].Text;
                dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["zielobjekt"] = gvRow.Cells[5].Text;
                dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["Action_Checked"] = gvRow.Cells[6].Text;
                dt.AcceptChanges();
            }

            return dt;
  }
```

// Method to remove Row from Gridview A

```
private DataTable RemoveRow(GridViewRow gvRow, DataTable dt)
 {
            DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("gruppenname = '" + gvRow.Cells[1].Text + "'");
            if (dr.Length > 0)
            {

                dt.Rows.Remove(dr[0]);
                dt.AcceptChanges();
            }
            return dt;

  }
```

// Now this is how i call them
// Method to Get Data from checked Row in Gridview Moglicheverteiler to add to Gridview Zugeteilte Emailverteiler

```
    private void GetData()
        {
            DataTable dt;
            if (ViewState["SelectedRecords"] != null) 
                dt = (DataTable)ViewState["SelectedRecords"];
            else
                dt = CreateDataTable();         

            for (int i = 0; i < gv_MoeglicheEmailverteiler.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
              CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)gv_MoeglicheEmailverteiler.Rows[i].Cells[6].FindControl("cb_CheckOneMoglicheverteilerRow");  string test = gv_MoeglicheEmailverteiler.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text;

if (gv_ZugeteilteEmailverteiler != null && chk.Checked) 
{
for (int j = 0; j < gv_ZugeteilteEmailverteiler.Rows.Count; j++) 
                    {
                        string actionChecked = gv_ZugeteilteEmailverteiler.Rows[j].Cells[6].Text;                     
                        if ((chk.Checked && actionChecked == "Bestaetigen")|| (chk.Checked && actionChecked == "Bestaetigt") || (chk.Checked && actionChecked == "TRUE") || (chk.Checked && actionChecked == "FALSE") || (chk.Checked && actionChecked == "Entfernen"))
                        {
                            dt = AddRow(gv_MoeglicheEmailverteiler.Rows[i], dt);

                            dt = AddRow(gv_ZugeteilteEmailverteiler.Rows[j], dt);
                            
                        }
                        else if (chk.Checked)
                        {
                            dt = AddRow(gv_MoeglicheEmailverteiler.Rows[i], dt);                          
                        }                      
                    }
                }
            }

            ViewState["SelectedRecords"] = dt;               
        }

        
        private void SetData()
        {
         
            if (ViewState["SelectedRecords"] != null)
            {
                DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["SelectedRecords"];
                for (int i = 0; i < gv_MoeglicheEmailverteiler.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)gv_MoeglicheEmailverteiler.Rows[i].Cells[6].FindControl("cb_CheckOneMoglicheverteilerRow");
                    if (chk != null)
                    {

                        DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("gruppenname = '" + gv_MoeglicheEmailverteiler.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text + "'");
                        chk.Checked = dr.Length > 0;

                    }
                }
            }         
        }
```

So in short am trying to figure out how i can save the checkboxes values into the viewstate just as i did with the Gridview Columns. Any ideas out there will be really appreciated. Ibeen stocked on the problem for months.

```
    // Bind ZugeteiltGridview For GetData Method
    private void BindZugeteilteGridviewForGetDataMethod()
    {
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["SelectedRecords"];
        gv_ZugeteilteEmailverteiler.DataSource = dt;
        gv_ZugeteilteEmailverteiler.DataBind();
        //CheckAddedRowFromMoglicheEmailverteiler();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `AutoPostback=true` - this is the problem. Don't do it this way.

Instead, add a button to execute the changes from Grid A to Grid B. You should be able to access the checkbox values then by looping over the GridView rows before they are databound - You might need a hidden field to store the `ID` of the item on each row. You than should - if you need to - fetch the data for that ID from the datastore rather than try and get it from the GridView. You can try of course but as they are DataBound controls I believe you need to fetch the text of the cell.

Once that is done than you can rebind the grid(s).

Make sure you don't databind the grid A before you loop over it or all you checkboxes will be gone.

Comment: Thanks, Salik for your response, I think thats another way to do it. i however created a dictionary with a string as key and an array with length 3 as the values. So i basically loop through the Grid A and collect the check values and store in my Global dictionary before binding the grid. I wrote a another method that loops through my Dictionary and the Grid and compare the Keys and restore the values from the array. I know thats not the best or easier way, but it kind of works for me at least for now.